# Java MVC framework closest to Asp.net mvc3?

Tags: java, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

this will probably get downvoted etc for being ambiguous, but I am strapped for time and was hoping that someone with much more experience can hop in here and give me a nod in the right direction.

I have been developing several mid-size business apps with a few developers in ASP.NET MVC(3). Me and the team need to produce a java EE web app. I'd like to keep things as consistent as possible -- I have used CakePHP in the past and noticed it was pretty much a breeze to jump into after the ASP.NET MVC Stuff.

What is the best/most similar MVC framework for Java? Alot of the guys just spent the last few months learning all the new MVC3/Razor stuff after coming from more "Classic ASP" or C/C++ design stuff. I really want to keep things as consistent as possible to avoid extra confusion.

Thanks!

Edit: Also I guess I should ask with your recommendation, if one particular IDE has much better integration than the other, I am curious about this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may consider JSF/Seam framework (or) Spring MVC. AFAIK, JSF/Seam resembles most like .NET MVC3.

Comment: FWIW, I ended up moving forward with JSF and JPA and it isnt too much of a jump in doing things

Comment: @Yablargo: That is good to hear. Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 2):

Just an alternative viewpoint to consider:  There are many more important factors to consider when choosing a framework beyond "is it similar to x, which I already know."  Think about what tools are best for solving the problem at hand and less about what is best/easiest for you.  In the long run, if you're going to work with Java on the enterprise, you're going to probably have to learn several other frameworks and move between them anyways.  You could really shoot your project in the foot if you choose JSF just because it is "like .NET."

And just so I sort of answer the question:  There isn't really a Java framework that approximates what Microsoft did with .NET MVC.  The whole "thing after ASP.NET" reminds me a lot of PHP and Spring before annotations based configuration.  Then again, I got away from .NET in 2009, so I should probably shut up now.

Comment: Fair enough. I guess I should clarify and mention that the portion of the app that will be web/MVC is relatively simple and just has a large volume of views/reporting. All of my data ingestion is done via pre-existing apps/data sources. The only requirement is that it runs on jetty (alongside another app already deployed) and avoids commercial/copyleft licensing unless the cost is reasonable

Comment: I wrote that answer back in January and got a drive-by downvote on May 6.  This site is truly bizarre!  What could I have said that could have possibly been worth the downvote?